# Toggle function in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking to develop an message inbox section.
The message subject will display in a loop.... That part is over, but the problem is how i can view the content part on clicking the subject by using "jQuery $this.next" function. i will put the code below

//php

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ ?>
    <div id="sub<?php echo $i; ?>" class="subject">subject<?php echo $i; ?></div>
    <div id="con<?php echo $i; ?>" class="content">content<?php echo $i; ?></div>   
    <?php 
} ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share your html and script code?

Comment: So you mean you will click on the `<div>` and you want to be notified of the text inside it?

Comment: yup,, by clicking the class "subject", the content should be "shown"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's assume you have the following structure and we assume that the body of every message is initially hidden:

```
<ul id="inbox">
    <li class="message">
        <h3 class="message-subject">Some subject</h3>
        <p class="message-body">Some content</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The following code will add a click handler on the element that holds every message, which will be invoked only when the message subject is clicked. The element following the message subject element will then be shown.

*Note: This technique is called event delegation and is quite more efficient that attaching one handler per subject element.*

```
$('#inbox').on('click', '.message-subject', function () {
    //.next() will retrieve the immediately following sibling of the h3 tag
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

EDIT: I see that you provided your HTML code now, but you should be good with my example.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3NW7C/

Comment: thanks for answer,,,
show function works,,,
but it isn't dynamic,,,,,
not working in loop, instead of showing corresponding content on clicking each subject it showing latest content on clinking first message,,, works only for first message subject

Answer (score 0):

just be aware your for loop says:
   `for($i=0; $o<10; $i++){ ?>`
if $o is not assigned you may not get the results you want try `for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ ?>` 
changing the 2nd var from $o to $i.

Happy coding :)

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't noticed that